# jQuery show / hide not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

Tried to look at all the other questions about why this isn't working, no luck. I'm loading this in my header:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#knee-tab").hide();
    $("#shoulder-tab").hide();
});
$(function () {
    $("#patient-portal-link").click (function (event) {
        $("#patient-portal-tab").show();
        $("#knee-tab").hide();
        $("#shoulder-tab").hide();
    });
}); 
$(function () {
    $("#knee-link").click (function (event) {
        $("#patient-portal-tab").hide();
        $("#knee-tab").show();
        $("#shoulder-tab").hide();
        }); 
}); 
$(function () {
    $("#shoulder-link").click (function (event) {
        $("#patient-portal-tab").hide();
        $("#knee-tab").hide();
        $("#shoulder-tab").show();
    }); 
});
```

Here are the links that are meant to call up the script:

```
<ul>
<li><a id="#patient-portal-link">Patient Portal</a></li>
<li><a id="#knee-link">Knee</a></li>
<li><a id="#shoulder-link">Shoulder</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then I have the three divs which are named as follows:

```
<div id="patient-portal-tab">Patient portal content</div>
<div id="knee-tab">Knee content</div>
<div id="shoulder-tab">Shoulder content</div>
```

The `knee` and `shoulder` divs hide correctly on page load, but the links do nothing. I'm using Google Chrome and when inspecting element, I get no errors reported for javascript. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need so many `$(function () {` calls, you even already have `$(document).ready(function() {` written out! Just use one DOM ready function to wrap up all of them.

Comment: If you edit your post and remove the errors then nobody can really follow the answers later. So for everybody who came too late, the ids of links on the bottom where like this `id="#patient-portal-link"` before the edit. So the jQuery selector didn't work on them properly.

Comment: Yes my apologies, had just discovered the error and did not know that was what was the problem. Kind of a knee-jerk reaction. Will return the original question to its former state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `#` characters from your ID values. The `#` character in jQuery denotes an ID of an element, so you would need two `#`'s (`##knee-tab`) for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have the # symbol infront of the Ids. ReWrite it like this and it will work

```
<li><a id="patient-portal-link">Patient Portal</a></li>
<li><a id="knee-link">Knee</a></li>
<li><a id="shoulder-link">Shoulder</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in your HTML code. The id's in HTML doesn't need the hash '#'.

Answer (score 1):

`$(function() ... )` is just shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() ...)` if i recall correctly. So you are using too many ready calls. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#knee-tab").hide();
    $("#shoulder-tab").hide();

    $("#patient-portal-link").click (function (event) {
        $("#patient-portal-tab").show();
        $("#knee-tab").hide();
        $("#shoulder-tab").hide();
    });{

    $("#knee-link").click (function (event) {
        $("#patient-portal-tab").hide();
        $("#knee-tab").show();
        $("#shoulder-tab").hide();
        }); 

    $("#shoulder-link").click (function (event) {
        $("#patient-portal-tab").hide();
        $("#knee-tab").hide();
        $("#shoulder-tab").show();
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2hkjd225/)

check this fiddle 
in this code you have entered extra # to the id 
overwrite your previous html to the html code given in fiddle